# Can we assign a wait queue to another directly?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a situation where i need to copy the wait queue to another wait queue after initializing it. Can i do this directly by assigning ? any side effects ?
This is what i want:

```
1. Initialize wait queue 1.
2. call poll_wait() on wait queue 1.
3. Copy wait queue 1 to wait queue 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *copy* one waitqueue into another one: every *wait* element may belong at most to the one waitqueue.

If you talk about *moving* waitqueue into another location, you can try, but note that it is not intended by design.

In case of `poll_wait` call, it certaintly doesn't support *moving* waitqueue. The thing is that `poll_wait()` call for *actual* poll tables (in `.poll` callback implementation) stores pointer to the waitqueue in `wait_address` field of `struct poll_table_entry` (defined in `include/linux/poll.h`).